# How do you recursively return data from a parent child hierarchy in R?

Tags: r, recursion

Consider this dataset:

```
myData = data.frame(parent = c(1,3,5,7,8,9)
                    ,child = c(2,4,6,8,9,10))
```

I want to filter this dataset down to only records that belong to parent # 7. In T-SQL, I'd accomplish this using a recursive common table expression. Is there a way to do something like this elegantly in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a more complex example, it's hard to see exactly what you need (as here there is no "recursion" per se. It's just one level deep. However, to answer your specific question, here are two way:

```
myData = data.frame(parent = c(1,3,5,7,8,9),child = c(2,4,6,8,9,10))

#Using Dplyr
library(dplyr)
myData %>% filter(parent  == "7")

#Using Base R
myData$child[myData$parent == 7]
```

**Edit:**

Per the comments below, I think this simple script will do it. There may be a simpler way but the do while loop below is the first that came to mind:

```
newParent = 7
answer <- c()
repeat{
  currentResult <- myData$child[myData$parent == newParent]
  if(length(currentResult) != 0){
    newParent <- currentResult
    answer <- c(answer, newParent)
  }else{
    break
  }
}

> answer
[1]  8  9 10
```

**Edit #2**

Here's the same thing rewritten recursively given that the OP was interested in seeing how it is done:

```
findChild <- function(myData, parent){
  currentChild <- myData$child[myData$parent == parent]
  if(length(currentChild) != 0){
    return(c(currentChild, findChild(myData, currentChild)))
  }else{
    return()
  }
}

findChild(myData, 7)
```

Comment: 7 is the parent of 8, 8 is the parent of 9, and 9 is the parent of 10. Sorry if the 1st few records added confusion. Essentially, I want to return all of the values that roll-up into 7 (8,9,and 10). Does that help?

Comment: @Sevyns: Is this what you mean then?

Comment: I think that would work for my purposes @user1357015 -thanks for that! I will give it a try later. I'm used to solving these types of problems with recursive logic on the T-SQL side, but a loop that checks to see if the results are != 0 seems feasible. Just curious, have you written recursive functions to solve other types of problems with R? I'm still fairly new to the language but really like it so far!

Comment: @Sevyns: Yep -- all the time. However, for the data structure here, there's really no need for a recursion. Since every child only has one parent, you always know exactly when to go and a loop is easier to debug. 

Also -- if you find the answer acceptable, would you please click the check mark to mark it as complete? This way the person answering gets credit :-).

Comment: @Sevyns: I've also added for you the recursive approach.

Comment: You beat me to it! I was going to ask very kindly for a recursive example as I can't promise the real world data I'm working with is a 1-to-1 between parents and children. Thanks again for the help (marked as answered)!!